# Is there a way to exclude third-party booking websites on Skyscanner?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

Most of the time I purchase tickets from airlines' websites after searching flights on Skyscanner, even if third parties occasionally offer cheaper tickets. Because I don't like signing up for so many websites and/or sharing my data with third parties.

Can I exclude third parties from search results and only see airlines' original prices?

Comment: Why not use a better search engine such as Google Flights? :)

Comment: @JonathanReez Just a habit I guess. :)

Comment: Are 3rd party sites paying Skyscanner? Are you?

Comment: @ugoren I don't know whether they are paying Skyscanner. I pay where (airline or 3rd party) I purchase tickets.

Comment: My point is that 3rd party sites pay Skyscanner for the right of being included. They're unlikely to offer a feature in their disfavour.

Comment: @ugoren I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, as of 2018 such a feature is not available on Skyscanner.